# Несколько плагинов в шаблоне Smarty

Tags: smarty

Собственно вопрос: Как из одного шаблона выполнить несколько плагинов с одним именем. Выполняется только первый.

Например:

```
{component name='news' action='view' count=5}
{component name='comment' }
```

Ну и естественно код, который что-то делает

```
function smarty_function_component($params, &$smarty){
 if ($params['name'] == 'news') {
   echo 'Новости';
 }
 if ($params['name'] == 'comment') {
   echo 'Комментарии';
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

несколько плагинов с одним именем никак не будут работать, смарти подключает только первый встретившийся, но судя по предоставленному вами коду, вы запускаете один и тот же плагин с разными параметрами, поэтому попробуйте так:

```
function smarty_function_component($params, &$smarty){
 if ($params['name'] == 'news') {
   return 'Новости';
 }
 if ($params['name'] == 'comment') {
   return 'Комментарии';
 }
}
```

**P.S.** хотя у меня и так как написано у вас отлично работает. проверьте синтаксис скорей всего ошибка в нем.

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, работает и первый вариант. На самом деле код у меня другой, а более простой и не проверил... Каюсь. Вопрос закрыт))